# It is possible to write NQP's precedence parser in Raku

Tags: grammar, raku, nqp

I'm trying to figure out how I can rewrite NQP's Precedence Parser in Raku :

The Precedence Parser is implemented here: https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/src/HLL/Grammar.nqp#L384
NQP should be a subset of Raku but the Grammar part seems to be specialized.

If I want to rewrite the Precedence Parser in EXPR() in Raku instead,
what would be the Raku Grammar primitives to use?
I.e. What would `cursor_start_cur()` translate to? is there a `cursor` in a Raku Grammar? How can I set `pos` of a Raku Match object ? What would  `$termcur.MATCH()` translate to, etc...

I am not searching for different ways of writing a Precedence Parser,
but rather want to  know whether it can be done in Raku in the same way that NQP does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jnthn` wrote in IRC:

```
rule EXPR { <termish> [<infix> <termish>]* } 
token termish { <prefix>* <term> <postfix>* }
```

and then done the precedence sorting in an **action** method.

There is an example https://github.com/Apress/perl-6-regexes-and-grammars/blob/master/chapter-13-case-studies/operator-precedence-parser-class.p6 from the book https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484232279 that implement the same structure.